# Safari vs Chrome Font rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm currently working on a project where I have a navigation.
Now for some animations I need the fonts/letters being display pixel perfect on every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge).

But now I got shocked when I saw that Safari displays the letters at the most top like you can see here:
[image]

In Chrome instead the font is correctly rendered vertically aligned in the center.
The two white lines you can see there are just ::after elements of the li.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  ...
  <li>
    <a href="...">News</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I already tried using the vertical-align property. But without success.
Is there any solution to this? I need that they are always rendered the same way.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085640/vertical-centering-in-safari. Please check if that solution using -webkit-* properties works for you.

Comment: Try to specify `line-height` in pixels. If that doesn't work, try to specify height in pixels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical centering in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085640/vertical-centering-in-safari)

Comment: @PeterMissick unfortunately doesnt solve the problem as just both (in chrome and safari) the text is displayed more at the bottom but then the difference still exists just lower.

Comment: @F.Igor unfortunately doesnt solve the problem as just both (in chrome and safari) the text is displayed more at the bottom but then the difference still exists just lower.

Comment: @YanaTrifonova Didn't work for me unfortunately. I was able to set the height but this doesnt change anything at the top alignment of the font in safari

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element) solved my problem. seems like it was a font related problem.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Font rendering in general, browsers will render font different ways. So a font may look different on google chrome compared to Firefox.

And if you wanted my honest opinion, I do not think a user would notice too much if it was a small menu, but I have a possible answer.

`font-synthesis: none` (In Safari)
could be a possible fix as browsers will try to interpret fonts. Realistically, there is no universal thing that I know that makes fonts/characters look the same.